# fill an array with getElementById

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementbyid

I am trying to fill an array with numbers that I have in my HTML file by using getElementById.

For the HTML, I am attempting to do this using:

```
<div id="E1_INV_Funds0">1</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds1">2</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds2">3</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds3">4</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds4">5</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds5">6</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds6">7</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds7">8</div>
```

and then using the following Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var graphData = [];

 function fillData(){
   for( var i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    graphData[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("E1_INV_Funds" + i).value);
    return graphData;
   }
}

console.log(graphData);

</script>
```

This returns nothing.

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: @faintsignal That's not the problem

Comment: @CertainPerformance Obviously OP is not that familiar with this function and the info will allow them to solve one of the problems. So I'm not sure what the purpose of your comment is.

Comment: OP is using `getElementById` just fine here - he's using it properly, so telling him to read the docs on it will not at all help solve the issue he's having.

Comment: @CertainPerformance OP is calling it fine, but does not seem familiar with the type of object returned, otherwise would not be attempting to access the `value` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, `return` immediately terminates the function before any of the iterations have finished. Another problem is that `.value` only works for input-like elements - to extract the text from a `div`, access its `textContent` property.

How about using `Array.from` and its built in `map`ping function, which doesn't require any external mutation?

```js
const graphData = Array.from(
  { length: 8 },
  (_, i) => Number(document.getElementById('E1_INV_Funds' + i).textContent)
);
console.log(graphData);
```

```html
<div id="E1_INV_Funds0">1</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds1">2</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds2">3</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds3">4</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds4">5</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds5">6</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds6">7</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds7">8</div>
```

`Array.from({ length }, mapFn)` is just the functional way of creating a new array of length `length`. Passing an object with a `length` property to `Array.from` creates an array of `undefined`s, and the second argument is the same as `Array.prototype.map`, applied to the resulting array before returning it. With `.map`, the first argument is the array value (useless here), and the second argument is the index of the item being iterated over, which is what we want. The `_` is just an indicator that the parameter there isn't going to be used.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: After spending some time going over your elegant solution, I'm having trouble looking up certain aspects of it. Would you mind explaining why you can specify the length this way? Also, can you explain why the first argument with the underscore character is necessary? And if you can point me to doc that explains in detail that would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for going to the trouble. :)

Answer (score 1):

You never invoked function `fillData()`, also there few more corrections, replace `value` with `innerHTML`, here `document.getElementById("E1_INV_Funds" + i).innerHTML`

and move outside of loop `return graphData;`

```js
var graphData = []; /* find all where id starts with `E1_INV_Funds` */
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=E1_INV_Funds]').forEach(function(el) {
  graphData.push(+(el.textContent || el.innerHTML) || 0); /* parse as number */
});
console.log(graphData);
```

```html
<div id="E1_INV_Funds0">1</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds1">2</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds2">3</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds3">4</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds4">5</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds5">6</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds6">7</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds7">8</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call fillData function, instead of printing the graphData array directly and also return should be placed outside of the for loop (once the computation is done). Also, to fetch the data from div element, you need to use innerText or innerHTML as per your requirement.

Find the working solution below.

```js
var graphData = [];

function fillData() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    graphData[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("E1_INV_Funds" + i).innerText);
  }
  return graphData;
}

console.log(fillData());
```

```html
<div id="E1_INV_Funds0">1</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds1">2</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds2">3</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds3">4</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds4">5</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds5">6</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds6">7</div>
<div id="E1_INV_Funds7">8</div>
```